# Cannot access kibana4 "Kibana: Unknown error while connecting to Elasticsearch"

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I cannot access kibana4 by the reason of "Kibana: Unknown error while connecting to Elasticsearch".Anyone can help me? thanks

**Error: unknown error**

```
at respond (xxxx:8001/index.js?_b=5930:81568:15)  
at checkRespForFailure (xxxx/index.js?_b=5930:81534:7)  
at xxxx/index.js?_b=5930:80203:7  
at wrappedErrback (xxxx/index.js?_b=5930:20882:78)  
at wrappedErrback (xxxx/index.js?_b=5930:20882:78)  
at wrappedErrback (xxxx/index.js?_b=5930:20882:78)  
at http://xxxx/index.js?_b=5930:21015:76  
at Scope.$eval (xxxx/index.js?_b=5930:22002:28)  
at Scope.$digest (xxxx/index.js?_b=5930:21814:31)  
at Scope.$apply (xxxx/index.js?_b=5930:22106:24)
```

**kibana4 log**

```
{"@timestamp":"2015-11-12T07:40:48.234Z","level":"info","message":"GET / 502 - 300062ms","node_env":"production","request":{"method":"GET","url":"/elasticsearch/","headers":{"connection":"upgrade","host":"10.169.216.155","authorization":"Basic a2liYW5hYWRtaW46dHJhaW5vci5raWJhbmE=","accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36","referer":"http://xxxx/","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch","accept-language":"zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6","cookie":"session_id=1bb8a52c4f9b442025d17a03072943a49eb8c101"},"remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":42499},"response":{"statusCode":502,"responseTime":300062,"contentLength":43}}
```

Comment: I have solved this problem by increase elasticsearch's memory.  Edit /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch:  uncomment  "ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g"